# FadeOut effect using Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to use FadeIn and FadeOut effect in my website ( Rails App ). But there seems to be problem with the FadeOut effect ( the text is not fading out slowly as in Wix demo Website ). Here is the script used:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").css("display", "none");
        $("body").fadeIn(2000);
        $("a.transition").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href;
            $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
        });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

Comment: You cannot fade out the body element :P

Comment: @infensus I just did a [test](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/KtPwz/) and you're absolutely right...changing the `opacity` has no effect on the `<body>`.  `<html>` on the other hand...

Comment: Are you certain your link has the transition class attached to it? inspect the element before clicking on it to make sure.

Comment: @infensus Yes you can, I just tried it. You can even open up the console on this page and try it.

Comment: can you provide us JSfiddle or link of your site

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to fading the body in/out, would be overlaying a white or black `div`.

### [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uLtxp)

Place an empty div at the top of your body element.

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

You can style it so that it takes up the entire viewport.

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  z-index: 314159;
}
```

Then flip the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` calls in your JavaScript.

```
$("#overlay").fadeOut(2000);
$("a.transition").click(function(event){
  linkLocation = this.href;
  $("#overlay").fadeIn(1000, redirectPage);
  return false;
});
```

You should be putting this CSS in the `<head>` section of your page to prevent flicker on page load.  Otherwise, some browsers could start showing the contents before your CSS finishes downloading.

Comment: +1 for thinking a little outside the box. That said, I hope OP elaborates a bit more on his issue, since his code really should work.

Comment: @Himanshu Once again, are you sure your links have the transition class?